# Javascript declaration

Tags: javascript

Hi this is a simple question. I was wondering is there any different when you declare something like this. Thanks

```
  selectedData[key](val)
```

and

```
  selectedData[key] = val
```

Comment: That __really__ depends on what `selectedData[key]` _is_. Your first example is a function invocation. The second one is just an assignment.

Comment: invocation and assignment are two different operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `selectedData[key](val)` is not a declaration, it's calling the function that is stored under the key `key` in the object `selectedData` and it's passing the parameter `val` to that function.

The other line `selectedData[key] = val` is assigning the value `val` to the key `key` in the object `selectedData`.

Comment: alright, it seems more clear now. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you're calling whatever is in selectedData[key] as a function with `val` as  an argument while in the second one you're assigning it.